# JavaFx Pane Button position

Tags: javafx, pane

As a layout I have a `Pane`.
How do I set the position of a button always in the right corner when windows size is changed?

```
Pane root = new Pane();

Button b = new Button("Button ");

b.setLayoutX(100);
b.setLayoutY(0);
root.getChildren().add(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Pane` is not a good fit for this kind of layout. You could use

- `StackPane`: This will align every single child to a corner, center of an edge or the center though.
- `AnchorPane`: By default this layout works the same as `Pane`, but if you set anchors, you can set the distance of a child from the top, left, right and/or bottom.

**Example:**

```
AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();

Button b = new Button("Button ");

// place button in the top right corner
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(b, 0d); // distance 0 from right side of 
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(b, 0d); // distance 0 from top

root.getChildren().add(b);
```