# JavaFx Pane adjusting to windows size

Tags: javafx, pane

How do I adjust the Pane to the windows size? So that when I change the window size the nodes also adjust to this situation.

```
Pane root = new Pane();

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    Button b = new Button("Button " + i);
    b.setLayoutX((i*100));
}
```

Comment: use AnchorPane.

Comment: Use a layout which automatically sizes and positions its managed children.

Comment: `GridPane` with `percentWidth`s in the column constraints seem to be the best way to go about this.

Comment: please don't ask the same (or extremely similar) question more than once - at least not without applying what you learned from the answer [to the previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58699331/203657). Also note, that you a) should read and understand a decent basic tutorial on javafx (see the tag wiki of javafx for options) and b) when having a problem, provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what doesn't work as you expect it to work.